# GNOME Do: Remap Summon Do to only <Super>

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-do

I am a heavy gnome do user and I have unbound the Super key from the gnome activities window so I can use it to summon gnome do.

In gnome do preferences it will only allow me to set the key binding to Super plus some other key. How can I bind summon do to just the super key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a little utility. `xcape` is included in the Ubuntu software repositories and can be installed using

```
sudo apt install xcape
```

**To bind pressing and releasing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to a custom action:**

1) Disable the binding of <kbd>Super</kbd> to "Show activities"

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
```

2) Assign a custom hotkey to your command, e.g. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

3) Use `xcape` to redirect pressing and releasing <kbd>super</kbd> to your custom hotkey

```
xcape -e "Super_L=Super_L|space"
```

Include this command in your startup programs. If it does not work reliably as such, then include a small delay before leading as in:

```
sh -c 'sleep 1 ; xcape -e "Super_L=Super_L|space"'
```